# Android Google Maps v2 Set Zoom Level in Miles

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want set zoom level of Google map in miles, 
Right now, i'm using this code, but I think it's wrong and need improvement.

> ```
> map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MYLOC, calculateZoomLevel()));
> ```

```
   public byte calculateZoomLevel() {    
    byte zoom = 1;
    // if distance is in KMs
    double E = 40075;
    // if distance is in Miles
    //double E = 21638;
    zoom = (byte) Math.round(Math.log(E / nearByRadius) / Math.log(2) + 1);
    // to avoid exeptions
    if (zoom > 21) {
        zoom = 21;
    }
    if (zoom < 1) {
        zoom = 1;
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "zoom level = " + zoom);
    return zoom;
}
```

Comment: did you got the solution for this? as I am also having the same requirement..

Answer (score 2):

i have similar task, i need to show map with center and N km radius.
Here is my solution

```
 private CameraUpdate getZoomForDistance(LatLng originalPosition,double distance){
    LatLng rightBottom = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(originalPosition,distance,135);
    LatLng leftTop = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(originalPosition,distance,-45);
    LatLngBounds sBounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(rightBottom.latitude,leftTop.longitude),new LatLng(leftTop.latitude,rightBottom.longitude));
    return CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(sBounds,0);

}
```

It uses this library [android-maps-utils](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)
Hope this will help you

Comment: what is 3rd parameter in computeOffset method, in computeOffset definition it is named as heading, but it is its purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

based on @alexandr response

```
fun newLatLngOffset(center: LatLng, dist: Int): CameraUpdate {
    return CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
        LatLngBounds.Builder()
            .include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, dist.toDouble(), 0.0))
            .include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, dist.toDouble(), 90.0))
            .include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, dist.toDouble(), 180.0))
            .include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, dist.toDouble(), 270.0))
            .build(), 0
    )
}
```

the main difference is that with him solution circle are circumscribed, in my are inscribed